# Dynamic Sql with Wait delay to check status

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to implement the logic , where the below code run for every 30 sec 
**until the [execution_result]** = 'Running'.

**The transaction get completed only when [execution_result] is <> 'Running'**

Below is the code, but it is unfortunately not working.

Thanks

```
BEGIN

;WITH CTES AS
(
SELECT   e.package_name ,
e.execution_id, 
e.[executable_name] , 
es.[execution_path] , 
es.[execution_duration] , 
es.start_time,
es.end_time,
[execution_result] = CASE ex.[status]
               WHEN 1 THEN 'created' 
               WHEN 2 THEN 'Running' 
               WHEN 3 THEN 'canceled' 
               WHEN 4 THEN 'failed' 
               WHEN 5 THEN 'pending' 

END 

FROM    [catalog].[executables] e 
INNER JOIN [catalog].[executable_statistics] es ON es.[executable_id] = e.[executable_id] 
INNER JOIN [catalog] .[executions] ex ON e.execution_id = ex.execution_id


)

DECLARE @execution_result varchar (100) 
set @execution_result = select execution_result from CTES

IF  @execution_result = 'Running'

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'

END
```

Comment: Not working??Please elaborate what is not working..like the error description you have..as I can see the variable @execution_result declaration and set statements are not correct.

Comment: @Deepshikha: getting error : Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 34
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Comment: Start over. No one can teach you basic syntax in a forum like this - and you have many errors. Firstly, there is no loop so the goal of "run every 30 sec" cannot be met. So I suggest you start over and break your task into steps. First, write a loop that runs once every 30 secs. And consider how problematic this approach is. Once your loop works, add a basic query to get your results (but do nothing with it). When that works, then add whatever your assignment to execution_result variable was intended to do. Note that you can't assign a row to a scalar variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the variable before defining common table expression CTES as below because a CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement that references some or all the CTE columns.

```
DECLARE @execution_result varchar (100) ;

WITH CTES AS
(
```

And set the value of variable as:

```
select @execution_result =  execution_result from CTES
```

Also to keep the code executing till the time the break condition is met which is here `[execution_result] is <> 'Running'` we can encapsulate the entire logic within a `While` loop as:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
--Declare all variables 
DECLARE @execution_result varchar (100) ;
--Define an infinite loop
WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN

                WITH CTES AS
                (
                 --All the logic goes here
                )
                select @execution_result =  execution_result from CTES
                --check exit condition here

                IF  @execution_result = 'Running'
                Begin
                     WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'
                     CONTINUE;
                End
                Else
                Begin
                     BREAK;
                End

    END;
```

Hope this pseudo code helps!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to re-execute the query after 30 seconds of wait to re-check the status. From the looks of your query, it looks like you check it only once and may be your program might be exiting in 30 seconds. May be you need a `do...while` loop kind of logic here.

Comment: this is actually a valid point. he's suggesting that you keep checking until you get the status you need.

Comment: @Deepak: i am trying to implement logic that keep checking until the status is running

Comment: @TULSI I believe you got the answer. I was suggesting you need to run this logic in a loop until you have status as RUNNING.

Answer (score -1):

The code below is worked for me but you can replace #tables with CTE and go on.

```sql
    create table #executables           (executable_id tinyint, execution_id tinyint, package_name nvarchar(20), executable_name nvarchar(20) )
    create table #executable_statistics (executable_id tinyint, execution_path nvarchar(100), execution_duration int, start_time datetime, end_time datetime)
    create table #executions            (execution_id tinyint, [status] tinyint)

    insert #executions (execution_id, [status]) values (1, 2)
    insert #executable_statistics (executable_id) values (1)
    insert #executables (execution_id, executable_id) values (1, 1)


    while 1 = 1
    begin
    select * into #results from (
        select
             e.package_name 
            ,e.execution_id
            ,e.executable_name 
            ,es.execution_path 
            ,es.execution_duration 
            ,es.start_time
            ,es.end_time
            ,execution_result = case ex.[status]
                when 1 then 'created' 
                when 2 then 'Running' 
                when 3 then 'canceled' 
                when 4 then 'failed' 
                when 5 then 'pending' 
                end
        from
            #executables e
            inner join #executable_statistics es on es.executable_id = e.executable_id
            inner join #executions ex on e.execution_id = ex.execution_id
        ) as t


    declare @execution_result varchar (100)
        set @execution_result = ''
     select @execution_result = execution_result from #results
     drop table #results

    if  @execution_result = 'Running'
        begin
            waitfor delay '00:00:30'
        end

    else return

    end

    --select * from #results

    --drop table #executables           
    --drop table #executable_statistics 
    --drop table #executions
```